# Responsive web design with increasing phone resolutions

Tags: android, css, responsive-design

I've been trying to learn about responsive web design and from the tutorials i found online i found out that you have to set a min-width to pixels to something like 480px

But this seems outdated to me because phones and tablets have really high resolutions these days (4k resolution on phones..)

How do i make a responsive website for 4k phones? They have the same resolution as high end computer monitors..

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261897/responsive-design-on-mobile-phones-with-higher-resolutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS's 'px' is an abstract unit which will adjust according to different devices. Phone with retina display can still have breakpoint of 480px. It does not mean it is 480 physical pixels.

Comment: Are you sure about it? The way you're saying is like "px" in CSS is relative. If it was relative, then we wouldn't need to try to make the webpage responsive.